# TexStudio starts compiling on its own

Tags: texstudio

When I linger with mouse above the text, TexStudio starts compiling. Really annoying. How can I disable this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable inline preview

- Go to "Configure preview"
- "preview" tab
- disable "auto update" and make "auto update delay" very high

Comment: I have the same problem. Compiler runs everytime I stop typing. But the procedure you said is not working to stop auto compilation.